# In R., What is the reason that summary function doesn't count non-numberic Value from my data?

Tags: r

-Data Example(named rp1) :

(A Value) :
(A1 10)
(A2 30)
(A1 20)
(A2 44)
(A1 50)
...

-My code:

> summary(rp1)
> A                Value
> Length:15          Min.   :12.0
> Class :character   1st Qu.:17.5
> Mode  :character   Median :22.0
> Mean   :20.8
> 3rd Qu.:24.5
> Max.   :26.0

I have imported data, that it's 1-row is Text(A1, A2) and 2-row is Numberic Value.

To inspect the each number of text, I used summary function to whole data.

I'm going to run t-test to this data. But as far as there is different with code example that I provided, I'm not able to progress.

-Code Example I provided
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWT9D.png)

Is this matter of data type? or something else?

I need help.

For trial, I changed the value of 1-row as Number, then summary counted it just fine.

But I want to count Non-Numberic things.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I could follow the question entirely but summary ( mean,median etc) would make sense for a numeric data type. If you just want a count - ie a count of number of rows you could nrows or length. hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But My leck of Knowledge, I have not solved it yet.